# How can I render the Page First before Executing a Background Task using Flask?

Tags: flask

I would like to train my deep learning models with flask. I can already train them through the commandline but I figured it would be nice to train them with a good UI.

I managed to create such a trainer however, I do have a bit of a problem with it.

```
@app.route('/train', methods=['POST'])
def train():
    architecture = get('architecture', str)
    network = get_architecture(architecture)
    network.train(...) # slow down happens here
    return render_template("begin_training.html")
```

I would like to render the page first to display the parameters given by the user before beginning the training but I don't know how to do it. If I keep it this way, I would have to wait for the training to finish first before the page is rendered. Is it possible to render the page first before executing the training? Or how do I execute training as a background task?

Comment: I really like RQ. Easy to setup; simple to deploy: [http://python-rq.org/](http://python-rq.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow tasks should be executed in background. There are several ways to do that. One of them is using `celery`, which is also documented in Flask document: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/

Comment: I tried following that but I'm having a bit of a problem with the broker set up. I'm using rabbitmq. I encounter this error: `onsumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine act
ively refused it.`

Comment: Consider creating a new question with your config and code.

Comment: Actually, I already made it work. Turns out, the issue lies on the firewall. I'll accept your answer since it does answer my question.